# Multiple connect button GUI PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to build a GUI interface in python 3 using PyQt5. I have connected a QPushButton to a QLineEdit so that I could clear whatever the user writes, something like this (working within a class):

```
self.textboxA = QLineEdit(self)
self.buttonA = QPushButton('Clear', self)
self.buttonA.clicked.connect(self.textboxA.clear)
```

However, what if I have multiple textboxes and I want the specific button to clear just a selected number of them (for example only textbox A and C)? I tried with:

```
self.textboxA = QLineEdit(self)
self.textboxB = QLineEdit(self)
self.textboxC = QLineEdit(self)
self.buttonA = QPushButton('Clear', self)
self.buttonA.clicked.connect(self.textboxA.clear,
                             self.textboxC.clear)
```

but it keeps writing me TypeError: Qt.ConnectionType expected, not 'builtin_function_or_method'

Which I don't really understand,

Can anyone help me?

Thanks so much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest and most elegant thing is to connect to each function:

```
self.buttonA.clicked.connect(self.textboxA.clear)
self.buttonA.clicked.connect(self.textboxC.clear)
```

if you have many, just use a for loop:

```
for textbox in (self.textboxA, self.textboxB, self.textboxC):
    self.buttonA.clicked.connect(textbox.clear)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget,
                             QLineEdit, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.textboxA = QLineEdit()
        self.textboxB = QLineEdit()
        self.textboxC = QLineEdit()
        self.buttonA  = QPushButton('Clear -> textboxA, textboxC')
        self.buttonA.clicked.connect(self.clearTextboxs)        

        main_layout.addWidget(self.textboxA) 
        main_layout.addWidget(self.textboxB)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.textboxC)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.buttonA)

        central_widget = QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(main_layout)

        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)        

    def clearTextboxs(self):
        self.textboxA.clear()
        self.textboxC.clear()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow() 
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]